# Create list of values from dictionary from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, map-function

I need to pass only values from list of dictionaries to a function.
The list of dictionaries looks like this

```
[ { "positive" : 515, "neutral" : 22, "negative": 1515 },
  { "positive": 15555, "neutral": 2525, "negative": 111}
  ......
]
```

and I need to get all the numbers for one key into a list so I can pass it to this function (below). (it shouldn't look like this, this is the only solution I was capable of). I need some more efficient solution, maybe something with *map* function or *list comprehensions*, but I have no idea how to use these.

```
bar_chart.add('neutral', [ dictList[0]['neutral'],dictList[1]['neutral'],dictList[2]['neutral'] ....... ['neutral'],dictList[23]['neutral'] ] )
bar_chart.add('positive', [ dictList[0]['positive'],dictList[1]['positive'],dictList[2]['positive'], ......... ,dictList[23]['positive'] ] )
```

Comment: `bar_chart.add('neutral', [item['neutral'] for item in dictList])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should take care of it in one line:

```
[bar_chart.add(key,[item[key] for item in dictList]) for key in dictList[0].keys()]
```

The comprehension assembles lists for all common keys in your list of dictionaries(reffered to as`item`) and then passes in the key and values into your `bar_chart.add` method.

The comprehension by itself produces a list of the common key values:

```
>>> [[item[key] for item in dictList] for key in dictList[0].keys()]
[[515, 15555], [22, 2525], [1515, 111]]
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
    dictlist =[ { "positive" : 515, "neutral" : 22, "negative": 1515 },
             { "positive": 15555, "neutral": 2525, "negative": 111}]

    poslist = []
    neutlist = []
    neglist = []
    for stuff in dictlist:
            poslist.append(stuff["positive"])
            neutlist.append(stuff["neutral"])
            neglist.append(stuff["negative"])
```

you will have only the values in the corresponding lists then...